# Case Sensitivity in FME Schema Mapper

Tags: fme-form, fme-transformer

I am using FME to translate data from one database to another and am using [Schema Mapper](https://www.safe.com/transformers/schema-mapper/) to help set attribute values where needed.

Unfortunately, it appears that Schema Mapper is case sensitive on input data, so I'm having to input all possible variations of a text value to ensure it's always transformed correctly.

For example, I might need to set source value `Midavalo`, `MIDAVALO`, `midavalo`, `MidaValo`, all to the same destination value, otherwise if I miss one and one of the features has that value then the schema mapper doesn't trigger on that value for that feature.

Is there a way to explicitly specify in FME somewhere (in the Schema Mapper table, or properties, or settings etc) to consider all possible text-case variations of the source when assessing the mapped values?

Comment: Unfortunately (for this case) the SchemaMapper *is* case-sensitive. The StringCaseChanger is the best solution, but you could create a temporary attribute to do that on, so you aren't changing your original attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also lowercase all the values first with a StringCaseChanger. Then you have a defined input value which you can map.

If you need to retain the original values you can duplicate them into a temporary attribute, lowercase that and then do the schema mapping on that attribute.

If your original data is

```
plot_id | species
      1 | Wolf
      2 | GIRAFFE
      3 | snAkE
```

You use (possibly) an AttributeManager to create the `species_lc` attribute with the original species value, and behind that a StringCaseChanger to lowercase the `species_lc` value. I don't have FME at hand, maybe the AttributeManager can also directly lowercase existing attributes, you'll have to try that.

```
plot_id | species | species_lc
      1 | Wolf    | wolf
      2 | GIRAFFE | giraffe
      3 | snAkE   | snake
```

See https://www.safe.com/transformers/string-case-changer/ and https://www.safe.com/transformers/attribute-manager/ .

Thanks @Mark Ireland for ideas.

Comment: That could be a good workaround - I'll take a look tomorrow.  It may cause other issues unless I can make the case change only for my schema mapper - I may need other values to stay as-is, but I'll tackle that if it arises

Comment: If that is the case you could duplicate the values into another attribute (maybe called "<attribute>_lc" or such), lowercase that and use it for schema mapping. Then use the original values for your other purposes.